# Solve::nsmet error message while trying to find symbolic solution for equation

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I would like to solve several equations for `x` and I'm looking for symbolic solutions.
The later ones might have some rather difficult or no result at all, but I think I am not handling the `Solve[]` command in the right way.

```
In[1]:= Solve[(x (V/(R x))^(-b))/(1 + b) == y && b > 0, x, Reals]
In[2]:= Solve[(2 E^(b (-Sqrt[F] + Sqrt[R x])) (-1 + b Sqrt[R x]))/(b^2 R) == y && b > 0, x, Reals]
In[3]:= Solve[(E^(b/F)*((R*x)/E^(b/(R*x)) + b*ExpIntegralEi[-(b/(R*x))]))/R == y && b > 0, x, Reals]
```

Mathematica returns the message `During evaluation of In[1]:= Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.`

What is the correct input for these types of problems?

Comment: The second one works if you remove b>0 and Reals and you get a warning about inverse functions with the result: `x->(1 + ProductLog[1/2 b^2 E^(-1 + b Sqrt[F]) R y])^2/(b^2 R)`

Comment: I don't know why it couldn't manage the first one, but it appears to satisfy `(y (1 + b))^b R/V == x^(b - 1)` s.t `x == ((y (1 + b))^b R/V)^(1/(b-1))`

Comment: Hi flinty! Oh yes, I also get your result for the second equation. The first Eq. can be solved manually, where you might have misread some brackets (I just took the Mathematica output that is rather poorly typeset). My result for the first one is `x == (y (b+1) V^b R^(-b))^(1/(b+1))`. It seems that Mathematica is **not** able to solve problems like `Solve[y == x (R x)^b, x]` but can solve other structured equations like `Solve[y == x x^b R^b, x]`. Is there any other function which can do this?